# What is the purpose of user.js file in generated node environment

Tags: javascript, node.js

I installed a plugin to allow me to set up a node.js environment in visual studio. Here is a screen shot of the files it provided me with...

[image]

Under routes, I have two files, `index.js` renders the home page, but I am not sure what the purpose of the `users.js` file. It contains the following code...

```
/*
 * GET users listing.
 */

exports.list = function (req, res) {
    res.send("respond with a resource");
};
```

and it is called by the `app.js` file as so...

```
var user = require('./routes/user');
...
app.get('/users', user.list);
```

Can anyone explain why the structure includes this file. In my previous node projects I simply ignored it, but I feel like it may come in handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in-short:

its kept for showing how to structure the routes. - you can delete it.

TLDR:

when you hit http://your-server-or-appdir-url:1234/users

it will send a response "respond with a resource".

I am not a visual studio guy, but this file is kept as a sample (just to show, how to include more routes).

```
app.get('/users', user.list);
```

assigns /users path to the user.list of routes/users.js export.